# writing a recurring code that takes previous defined instance and creates new one

Tags: python, recurring

I have to do something like below. I have one instance `v1` and from there on, I have to create other instances by running certain function over it in a recurring way.

```
v2 = vclass.makesomething(v1,a).attribute1()
v3 = vclass.makesomething(v2,a).attribute1()
v4 = vclass.makesomething(v3,a).attribute1()
.
.
.
```

The only thing I thought was using a change in name of variable like having `v+str(i)` but that is a bad way to proceed to the problem. Is there a way to create a recurring code for this?

May be I have phrased the question badly, but I did not know how should I express the problem.

second method I found to work along with what @Duck suggested,

```
vtemplist = [vertex1]
for i in range(number_of_instances_needed)):
    vtemplist.append(vclass.makesomething(vtemplist[-1],a).attribute1())
```

Comment: Do you know how often you'll have to do it?  I would think the best way would be a `for i in range(start, stop, step)` loop, where you're assigning the attributes to an array.

i'm not familiar with python though, so maybe there is some limitation i'm not aware of there.

Comment: Hey @mykepwnage I was trying to do something along the lines as you suggested and I found above technique to work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def recur(v, times):
    if (times != 0):
        v = vclass.makesomething(v,a).attribute1()
        return recur(v, times-1)
    return v
```

Now you can call `recur` with the initial value of `v` and how many times you would like to recurse.

Edit: I was assuming you only were interested in the last instance. If not, you can use the following, which will return a list of `v` objects.

```
def recur(v, times, lst=[]):
    if (times != 0):
        v = vclass.makesomething(v,a).attribute1()
        lst.append(v)
        return recur(v, times-1, lst)
    return lst
```

Comment: Hey @Duck this works. thanks for this idea. It is as simple as it can get and yet elegant :) I am not from CS background so kind of suck with idea of recursion.